# Counter in Java (non GUI)

Tags: java

I am trying to make a counter so that as long as the person keeps on responding yes during the loop, it keeps counting and then after each response says how many times already the person has said yes (y) in this case.

Here is the code so far:

```
/**
* Write a description of class dummygameclass here.
* 
* @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */

   import java.util.*;
          public class dummygameclass
    {
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
  public static void main(String [] args) throws InterruptedException{

   Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

   int i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6, i7, i8, i9;
   String s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8, s9;
 boolean loop = true;
            while(loop=true){
   System.out.println("You walk up the stairs, but you shockingly see yourself back in the same room, same position, climb again?");
       s3 = reader.next();
       if(s3.equals("y")){
            System.out.println("You walk up the stairs, but you shockingly see yourself back in the same room, same position, climb again?");
       s3 = reader.next();
       int counter = 0;
       counter++;
       System.out.println(counter);

        }else if(s3.equals("n")){

            System.out.println("You have chosen not to climb the staircase.");
            loop=false;
            break;

        }


  }
  }
  }
```

But this doesnt do me any good, what can I do?  The counter just either doesn't show anything or a '1' but nothing else?

Comment: You're setting counter = 0 every time the loop runs.

Comment: This is clearly homework. So I'll give some general advice instead of doing it for you. Don't create nine identically-named variables of every type at the start of every method. Give your variables meaningful names. Also, try to align the lines of your code so that the braces match up veritcally. This will make your blocks of code easier to debug.

Comment: @zerobandwidth, actually I'm still in high school. This is extra curricular for fun!

Comment: @zerobandwidth, actually I got it after the answer, I needed to declare it outside the loop.

Comment: @Amad27 Good times. Keep at it! ^_^

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried declaring your counter outside of you while loop.  Along with your int i1 i2 etc. type int counter; and initialize it to 0. It should work then.

Answer (score 2):

You declare the variable counter in the if and initialize to 0 also in it!
The variable counter must be declared and initialized to 0 before the while.

```
while(loop=true)
```

You are affecting a value to loop, not comparing !
Moreover it is useless to compare that true == true, while(loop) is enough.

Answer (score 0):

a few changes to the code.
main problem in declaring a variable inside the correct scope.

```
/**
* Write a description of class dummygameclass here.
* 
* @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */

import java.util.*;
public class dummygameclass {

  // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
  public static void main(String [] args) throws InterruptedException{

    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6, i7, i8, i9;
    String s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8, s9;
    boolean loop = true;

    int counter = 0; // moved to outside of the loop scope        

    while(loop=true){
        System.out.println("You walk up the stairs, but you shockingly see yourself back in the same room, same position, climb again?");
        s3 = reader.next();

        if(s3.equals("y")){
            //System.out.println("You walk up the stairs, but you shockingly see yourself back in the same room, same position, climb again?");
            //s3 = reader.next();
            //int counter = 0;
            counter++;
            //System.out.println(counter);
        }
        else if(s3.equals("n")){
            System.out.println("You have chosen not to climb the staircase.");
            loop=false;
            //break; // don't need both break and setting loop to false
        }
    }

    // moved to outside of the loop scope, printed once after loop ends
    System.out.println(counter);

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while(loop==true)
```

Or

```
while(loop)
```